# What are questions you ask yourself before rigging anything?

Tags: rigging

When rigging anything, what are questions to consider asking yourself mentally before doing so?

Comment: This is quite broad for Stackexchange...

Comment: Hello :). This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than factual answers. Please update it with more specific info. If you can't, https://blenderartists.org/ is probably a better place for this question.